# Delete GMail chats via IMAP

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I've created a small script with Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap to interact with GMail. Everything works fine so far, but I can't remove my chats?
So I tried moving them to 'Bin':

```
REQUEST: TAG18 COPY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 "[Google Mail]/Bin"
RESPONSE: TAG18 NO [ALERT] Chats can only exist in the Chat folder (Failure)
```

Didn't work obviously...
Than I tried setting the deleted flag on them:

```
REQUEST: TAG19 STORE 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 +FLAGS (\Deleted)
RESPONSE: TAG19 NO STORE attempt on READ-ONLY folder (Failure)
```

Didn't work out either.

What could I do to move the chats to the Trash? I can do it manually within the GMail interface, but I'd like to do it automatically...

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure the chats are part of the IMAP API, look for someone more specialized than me though.

Comment: Looks to me like Truth is right.  IMAP can only deal with messages.  I didn't even know Chats could be accessed at all via IMAP.

Comment: Settings -> Labels: Check the box for Chats which says something like "IMAP" on it... It works. I can download them. But seems not delete (or move to bin) them.

Comment: I just found the same thing in my mail client. I'm guessing they're read-only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Searching around](https://www.google.com/search?q=gmail%20imap%20chats%20read%20only) you see that other programmers have encountered the same issue: that the chats label appears read-only. All the search results are other programmers providing their own feedback on the problem and confirming that the chats label is indeed read-only. Frustratingly, I could locate no official documentation from Google specifically on the subject.

The closest "official" post I could find on the subject was from a comment made by Googler [Brandon Long](https://plus.google.com/112658633592720298303/posts) on a [Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/101174951617223562800/posts/LUFdweFDaCe): [Gmail Liberates Recorded Chat Logs Via IMAP - Data Liberation](http://dataliberation.blogspot.com/2011/09/gmail-liberates-recorded-chat-logs-via.html). Emphasis added.

**Comment on Sep 15, 2011**

> Yes, currently chats are only displayed in the Chats folder. **The Chats
>   folder is also currently read-only**, you can only export chats from
>   there... though you can then upload those chats to another folder
>   usually without issue. There are some technological reasons for this,
>   chats have a bunch of special handling in the Gmail server, and are
>   not 'real' email messages. This means that in some cases, a chat
>   message may violate the IMAP spec in terms of message immutability. It
>   was considered safer to silo them only in the Chats folder, which
>   could ultimately be unsubscribed from or hidden entirely from IMAP if
>   a user encounters problems with their client. We have fixed a number
>   of bugs with chat exposure, hence the reason this has launched, but
>   we're still a bit leery of potentially breaking things. Historical
>   note, chats were exposed up until the last couple weeks before the
>   initial IMAP launch, but the large number of bugs made us decide to
>   just hide them. The DLF team has been instrumental in working to
>   expose them for your liberation pleasure.
>
> Note you can access the full list of labels on any message (chat or
>   otherwise) by using the X-GM-EXT1 extension,
>   http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/imap/, and using the X-GM-LABELS
>   message fetch attribute